# Изменить заголовок приложения при переключении вкладок

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

С самой программной сменой заголовка приложения проблем нет (буду делать это через `getActionBar().setTitle()`); как короче всего реализовать получение текущей вкладки? Знаю, есть метод `onTabSelected`, но не нашел нормальных (= лаконичных) примеров. В идеале я вижу окруженный аналогичным `onTabSelected` методом блок `switch-case`:

```
...
tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1");
...
 switch (tag) {
    case "tab1":
        getActionBar().setTitle("Вкладка1");
    case "tab2":
        getActionBar().setTitle("Вкладка2");
    case "tab3":
        getActionBar().setTitle("Вкладка3");
    case "tab4":
        getActionBar().setTitle("Вкладка4");
    default:
        break;
}
```

Я создал вкладки через TabHost (есть и другие способы, как оказалось).

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите в сторону TabLayout. TabHost - это древний вариант. tabLayout работает с viewpager. у TabLayout есть addOnTabSelectedListener. Туда положите TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener и переопределите ontabSelected

```
tabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            switch (tab.getPosition()) {
        case 0:
            getActionBar().setTitle("Вкладка1");
            break;
        case 1:
            getActionBar().setTitle("Вкладка2");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Обязательно попробую. Я очень долго искал решение, как сделать во вкладке иконку без заголовка; в `TabLayout` возможно легко убрать заголовок и оставить только иконку?

Comment: Вот так можно задать иконку

Comment: tabs.addTab(tabs.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.walk), 1); это я задаю иконку для второй вкладки. Текста по умолчанию нет